# JSS Page load issue

Tags: jss

I have one website which is in `Sitecore 9.2 and JSS`. This website already deployed on the QA environment but the issue is that when I load the website the first time it displays some text after that it displays a blank page and after 2-3 seconds it displays all text, images. When I try to reload the website, it works fine because of the cache.

I have checked this [URL](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23021/performance-issue-jssreact) but it is not suggested if we have dynamic queries.

I know that it takes time to convert JSON into HTML but what can be the solution for the first time?

Comment: We encountered similar issue in our React app with JSS while working in integrated mode. Temporarily, we used a loader animation to improve the UX. Finally, our react team was able to resolve it. I will recommend to check this from frontend perspective as well.

Comment: @GhanendraSingh It would be a great help if you could tell me what you have done in react to resolve this issue?